# Google Cloud Function Environment Variables Directory

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I've got a Cloud Function working properly, but now I'd like to obfuscate some credentials with environmental variables. When I try running this command:

```
gcloud beta functions deploy my-function --trigger-http --set-env-vars user=username,pass=password --runtime nodejs6 --project my-project
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function load error: File index.js or function.js that is expected to define function doesn't exist in the root directory.
```

I created the function using the GCP web UI, and I can't find the directory where the function lives to *cd* into. Presumably running the same command from the directory that the function lives in would work.

Where do cloud functions live in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check [the details of the function deployment on the logs](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?customFacets=protoPayload.request.function.sourceUploadUrl&limitCustomFacetWidth=false&interval=NO_LIMIT&advancedFilter=protoPayload.methodName%3D%22google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.CreateFunction%22%0AprotoPayload.request.function.sourceUploadUrl:*), you'll notice field `protoPayload.request.function.sourceUploadUrl` contains a URL where your source code is uploaded during the deployment.

This URL is is in the form of `https://storage.googleapis.com/gcf-upload-<region>-<random>/<random>.zip`. This means that the function is uploaded that GCS bucket. That GCS bucket is not on your project (it's from Google), so you won't have direct access to the files. You can download the files stored on that bucket through the console (the "Download zip" button on the source page).

The upload bucket can also be found through

```
gcloud functions list --format='table[](name,sourceUploadUrl)'
```

Knowing this, you have 2 paths:

- Use another way of deploying the function (e.g. from a source repo)
- Use the API to [patch](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.functions/patch) the function

I'm partial to the second option, since it's really easy to execute:

```
curl -XPATCH -H"Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" -H'content-type:application/json' 'https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<PROJECT_ID>/locations/<REGION>/functions/<FUNCTION_ID>?updateMask=environmentVariables' -d'{"environmentVariables":{"user":"<USERNAME>", "password":"<PASSWORD>"}}'
```

However, if you need to access anywhere Google related, rather than pass user/password, it's best to use the application default credentials, and providing access to the service account on the resource. To find out the service account used by your function, you can run:

```
gcloud functions list --format='table[](name,serviceAccountEmail)'
```